# How to dump GHC simplifier output in human-readable form?

Tags: haskell, command-line, ghc

I have the following program:

```
data Peano = Zero | Succ Peano deriving (Show)

add Zero     b = b
add (Succ a) b = add a (Succ b)

mul Zero     b = Zero
mul (Succ a) b = add b (mul a b)

four x = let two = Succ (Succ Zero) in mul two two
```

I want to get something like this from GHC:

```
add =
  \ ds b ->
    case ds of
      Zero ->
        b
      Succ a ->
        add
          a
          (Succ b)

mul =
  \ ds b ->
    case ds of 
      Zero ->
        Zero
      Succ a ->
        add
          b
          (mul a b)

four =
    let
      two =
        Succ
           (Succ Zero)
    in
    mul two two
```

The best I managed to get is

```
ghci -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-module-prefixes -dsuppress-uniques foo.hs
```

but it steel required a lot of manual removal of GHC generated stuff to get the code above. Is there a switch for GHC or a third party script that does the cleanup?

Is there a way at least to get rid of `case {tick (main:Main, 8)} @ (State# RealWorld) of _ { __DEFAULT ->`?

Comment: The `tick` annotations are generated by HPC, so disabling it should get rid of them, I think.

Comment: I don't know how. I didn't turn it on - see the command line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're in luck! There is a tool for the job: [ghc-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core).

ghc-core wraps ghc with a command line wrapper that displays GHC's optimised core and assembly output in a human readable, colourised manner, in a pager.

Usage - just replace `ghc` with `ghc-core`:

```
   ghc-core A.hs  

   ghc-core -fvia-C -optc-O3 A.hs
```

Comment: (That said, you're not going to get it more readable than this.  Also, install `ghc-core` with `cabal install ghc-core`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do much about that.

Comment: What if I am building my program using cabal? Can I still use ghc-core somehow?

Comment: I think it should now be `ghc-core -- -optc-O3 A.hs` instead.

Comment: @JanStolarek `cabal exec ghc-core Path/To/Module.hs`