# Haskell: function composition (.) vs function application ($) when it comes to performance?

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, when performance matters and using dollars or dots are both valid options, is one better than the other? Will one result in a performance gain over the other?

For example, given `(foo . bar. baz) value` and `foo $ bar $ baz value`, is one faster than the other?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, with an example?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can find an example where they differ in performance.

Comment: You can be as detailed as you want here, but the answer ultimately is "No" based on the fact that it would just be ridiculous for them to have differing performance. Quite frankly this is like asking if "++i" or "i++" is faster; sure, one of them might be faster without trivial optimizations, but under any reasonable compiler you don't derive your performance from trivialities like this.

Comment: Surely you mean `(foo . bar . baz) value`.

Comment: Oh, have you tried `foo (bar (baz value)))`?

Comment: @Bergi This one handicaps readability too much for my taste.

Answer (score 15):

If you are compiling with optimizations (`-O2`), GHC will nearly certainly inline both `.` and `$` and produce `foo (bar (baz value))` in both cases (and then optimize it further). "Nearly" is just in case; inlining is one of most basic optimizations GHC does, and both `.` and `$` are very simple and inlining them should always be a win, but I may not be thinking of some particular case. (One case I *can* think of when inlining them is harder is when they are partially applied, or passed to a higher-order function, but that's not the example given; or there could be a [rewrite rule](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) which fires *before* inlining and only covers one of these cases.)

However, you can always test it in your specific situation using e.g. [Criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/). You can also verify that inlining happened by [asking GHC to output Core files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693638/how-to-dump-ghc-simplifier-output-in-human-readable-form).

Comment: What do you mean by "nearly certainly"? Are there cases where the compiler won't inline?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron I've edited the answer to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: What about lists? Do intermediate lists get created in-between each application or composition? What about stream fusion?